# Authentication error after deployment: 'jwt must be provided' – discrepancy between local server and production deployment

Tags: authentication, jwt, render.com

When I deployed my project, when I hit login, it throws an error:

> jwt must be provided

But on my local server, it works perfectly fine.

**Note**: I have used Random `JWT_secret key = wyufgeeubw`

My middleware/auth.js code =>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4gSU.png)

My routes auth.js code =>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Bq2.png)

I have entered the jwt secret key in environment variable in the render and tried re deploy both frontend and backend code

Comment: Please try not to use pictures in your post.